# How prove this here exsit $b\in R$,such $S=\{(b,b,\cdots,b)\}$,if $f(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n})$ is the set of minimum and maximum points.

Tags: inequality, polynomials

Assmue $f(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n})$ is a second degree real polynomial with $n(n\ge 2)$ variables.
Let $S$  be such that $f(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n})$ is the set of minimum and maximum points.
In other words：
$$S=\{(b_{1},b_{2},\cdots,b_{n})\in R^n| f(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n})\le f(b_{1},b_{2},\cdots,b_{n}),\forall (x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n}\in R^n\}\bigcup \{(b_{1},b_{2},\cdots,b_{n})\in R^n| f(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n})\ge f(b_{1},b_{2},\cdots,b_{n}),\forall (x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n}\in R^n\}$$

Assmue $f(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n})$ is a symettric polynomial in $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n}$,and $S$ is a finte non-empty set.

show that:

there exsit $b\in R$,such
$$S=\{(b,b,\cdots,b)\}$$

My idea: let 
$$f(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n})=x^2_{1}+x^2_{2}+\cdots+x^2_{n}$$ is symettric polynomial,then we take
$$S=\{(0,0,\cdots,0)\}$$ such it

But for this problem I can't prove it,Thank you

Comment: Take $n=2$. If $(b_1,b_2)$ is a local minimum of $f$ then likewise $(b_2,b_1)$ is a local minimum. What shape of $f$ can you expect on the segment of the line connecting both points?

Answer (score 4):

Any real symmetric polynomial $f$ of degree $\leq2$ in the variables $x_1$, $\ldots$, $x_n$ can be written in the form
$$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=a_0+ a_1 \sigma_1+a_2\sigma_1^2 + a_3\sigma_2\ ,\tag{1}$$
where $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ denote the elementary symmetric polynomials of degree $1$ and $2$ in the $x_i$. Since $\sigma_1^2=(x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2)+2\sigma_2$ we can replace $(1)$ by the more convenient form
$$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=c_0+ c_1 \sigma_1+c_2\sigma_1^2 + c (x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2)\ .\tag{2}$$
When $c=c_2=0$ then $f$ is constant or linear, and $S={\mathbb R}^n$ or $=\emptyset$, in accordance with the claim.

When $c=0$ and $c_2\ne 0$ then $f$ depends only on $\sigma_1$, and assumes a minimum or a maximum on some hyperplane $\sigma_1={\rm const.}$. This hyperplane certainly contains a point of the form $(b,b,\ldots,b)$.

Finally assume $c\ne0$, and let $p\in S$. Then necessarily 
$${\partial f\over\partial x_i}=c_1+2c_2\sigma_1+2c x_i=0\qquad(1\leq i\leq n)$$
at $p$, which implies that all $p_i$ are equal.

Comment: Oh,It's nice! Thank you +1

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a simple reason why this is true. The set $S$ of extremal points of a second degree polynomial must be an affine subspace. An affine subspace which is invariant under permutations of the coordinates must contain a point on the form $(p,\ldots,p)$.

To see this, assume we have two distrinct points
$P=(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$ and $Q=(q_1,\ldots,q_n)$ both in $S$. Let $l$ be the line through them. The restriction of $f$ to the line $l$ is now a second degree polynomial one a line (i.e. in one variable) with two extremal points, which is only possible if it is constant.

To write it out more pedantically: the second degree polynomial $g(t)=f(tQ+(1-t)P)=a+bt+ct^2$ cannot have two different extrema unless $g(t)$ is constant.

Thus, if $P,Q\in S$, the line through $P$ and $Q$ must be contained in $S$. More generally, for any set $P_1,\ldots,P_k\in S$, $S$ must also contain the affine space spanned by these points:
$$\left\{\sum_i t_iP_i\middle| \sum_i t_i=1\right\}\subset S.$$

If $P=(p_1,\ldots,p_n)\in S$ where $S$ is an affine space and symmetric under permutations of the $p_i$, then the mean of all permutations of $P$ is $\bar P=(\bar p,\ldots,\bar p)$ where $\bar p=(p_1+\cdots+p_n)/n$. The mean $\bar P$ must also be in $S$ since it is in the affine space spanned by the permutations of $P$.

Moreover, either the point $(p,\ldots,p)\in S$ is unique, or the while line $(p,\ldots,p)$ is in $S$.

Comment: A nice argument.